# C# Json deserisalization

Tags: c#, json

In C# how can I select only "GroupType" from the json below.
Thanks.

```
{
    "QnACollection": {
        "QnA": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "question": "What was your childhood nickname?"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "question": "In what city was your mother born?"
            },
            {
                "GroupType": "RUN",
                "id": 45,
                "question": "What is the first name?"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var value = (string)JObject.Parse(json)
            .Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "GroupType");
```